# Aligning multiple pandas series by date index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have n `pandas series`. They mostly have the same amount of data but not always.

```
print(str(len(dfS1)))
print(str(len(dfS2)))
print(str(len(dfS3)))
print(str(len(dfS4)))

3025
3026
3025
3026
```

I need to make sure that each day row is aligned correctly, I do for example:

```
dfj = dfS1.join(dfS2, how='outer', rsuffix='_1').join(dfS3, how='outer', rsuffix='_2').join(dfS4, how='outer', rsuffix='_3')
```

However, if I print out the resulting `dataframe` **dfj** ,

```
print(dfj)

          date   close     date_1  close_1     date_2  close_2     date_3  \
0    2007-01-24  143.99 2007-01-24    44.29 2007-01-25   124.80 2007-01-25 

      close_3  
0       77.80   
....
```

as you can see, the joined rows are not aligned. Row 1 contains values for different dates.

How do I make sure that each row contains the value where the dates all match? So for example, row 1 would start where all dates are the same in each `dataframe`. Every row where there isn't a matching date in all the other `dataframes` would be `dropped`.

I realize that I can loop and create the `dataframe` by hand, but I am assuming that `pandas` has already a built in way to do this.

Comment: The default is to join based on the `index` if you do not specify an `on` argument. Set the date column to be the index before the joins, or specify `on='date'`.

Comment: Thank you that works.  Then just drop NaNs...

Comment: Might also be able to just use an `inner` join in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You have not stated what you want to join on.

```
dfj = dfS1.join(dfS2, on='date_field_name', how='outer', rsuffix='_1')
```

See the pandas documentation for full detail of a [dataframe.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join)

---

***Also, if you want to drop rows that don't have a matching date for all frames:***

For every Dataframe/Series being joined, you want to use *how='inner'*
   rather than 'outer'.